# Is there an easier way to update checkbox price?

Tags: javascript, html

The code I have below is good. As I check off some boxes the total price will update, however, I noticed that I have to code each value for every task as well as every combination of boxes checked off. Is there an easier way where I can write the value of each task and whichever boxes I check 
 off, it will add the total cost for me automatically?

```js
function checkPrice() {
  var price = 0;

  if (document.getElementById("box-4").checked == true) {
    price = 5;
  }

  if (document.getElementById("box-5").checked == true) {
    price = 4;
  }

  if (document.getElementById("box-6").checked == true) {
    price = 5;
  }

  if (document.getElementById("box-1").checked == true) {
    price = 5;
  }

  if (document.getElementById("box-1").checked == true && document.getElementById("box-2").checked == true) {
    price = 7;
  }

  if (document.getElementById("box-1").checked == true && document.getElementById("box-3").checked == true) {
    price = 12;

  }

  if (document.getElementById("box-2").checked == true && document.getElementById("box-3").checked == true) {
    price = 10;
  }

  if (document.getElementById("box-1").checked == true && document.getElementById("box-2").checked == true && document.getElementById("box-3").checked == true) {
    price = 17;

  }

  document.getElementById("price").innerText = "Total Price: " + "$" + price;
}
```

```html
<label for="bedroomcleaning">Bedroom: </label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-4" onclick="checkPrice()">Dust all ceiling fans/light/fixtures within reach.
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-5" onclick="checkPrice()"> Change sheets and/or fold clothes if requested by client.
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-6" onclick="checkPrice()"> Straighten up, put toys away, make beds, fold clothes and put on bed. Straighten papers and put in a pile. DO NOT THROW AWAY ANY PERSONAL ITEMS!
<br>
<br>
<label for="bathroomcleaning">Bathroom: </label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-1" onclick="checkPrice()"> Clean bowl and wipe down toilet cover, seat, under seat, base and behind the base.
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-2" onclick="checkPrice()"> Clean all mirrors.
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-3" onclick="checkPrice()"> Clean countertops and backsplashes.
<br>
<label for="bathroomprice" id="price">Total Price: </label>
```

Comment: Yeah sure there is. You just have to add an onclick function on each. And on your script you get its values

Comment: Your function needs a frame of reference. Pass `this` and use it in your function to update that element.

Comment: @isherwood Can you write it out for me so I can see what your explaining?

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. You have labels without inputs and inputs without labels. Your javascript is extremely verbose. I can fix this. The problem is that I don't see the logic of your pricing. Please: can you write down the logic of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use eventListeners and loop over the checked boxes

Note I have wrapped the boxes in a label so you can click the text too.

```js
function sumIt() {
  var price = 0;
  document.querySelectorAll("[id^=box]:checked").forEach(function(box) {
    price += box.checked ? 5.00 : 0;
  })
  document.getElementById("total").innerText = "$" + price.toFixed(2);
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.querySelectorAll("[id^=box").forEach(function(box) {
    box.addEventListener("click", sumIt);
  });
})

// forEach polyfill for Edge and IE 
if (typeof NodeList !== "undefined" && NodeList.prototype && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
  NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}
```

```html
Bedroom:<br>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="box-4">Dust all ceiling fans/light/fixtures within reach.</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="box-5">Change sheets and/or fold clothes if requested by client.</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="box-6">Straighten up, put toys away, make beds, fold clothes and put on bed. Straighten papers and put in a pile. DO NOT THROW AWAY ANY PERSONAL ITEMS!</label><hr>
Bathroom:<br>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="box-1">Clean bowl and wipe down toilet cover, seat, under seat, base and behind the base.</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="box-2">Clean all mirrors.</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="box-3">Clean countertops and backsplashes.</label><br> Total Price: <span id="total"></span>
```

If you need different prices, add them as value or data-price:

```js
function sumIt() {
  var price = 0;
  document.querySelectorAll("[id^=box]:checked").forEach(function(box) {
    price += box.checked ? +box.value : 0; // or +box.getAttribute("data-price")
  })
  document.getElementById("total").innerText = "$" + price.toFixed(2);
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.querySelectorAll("[id^=box").forEach(function(box) {
    box.addEventListener("click", sumIt);
  });
})
// forEach polyfill for Edge and IE 
if (typeof NodeList !== "undefined" && NodeList.prototype && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
  NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}
```

```html
Bedroom:<br>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="box-4" value="5">Dust all ceiling fans/light/fixtures within reach.</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="box-5" value="4">Change sheets and/or fold clothes if requested by client.</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="box-6" value="5">Straighten up, put toys away, make beds, fold clothes and put on bed. Straighten papers and put in a pile. DO NOT THROW AWAY ANY PERSONAL ITEMS!</label><hr>
Bathroom:<br>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="box-1" value="5">Clean bowl and wipe down toilet cover, seat, under seat, base and behind the base.</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="box-2" value="2">Clean all mirrors.</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="box-3" value="7">Clean countertops and backsplashes.</label><br> Total Price: <span id="total"></span>
```

Comment: @mplugjan Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your post gives me this error: `"Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach\`"`

Comment: Ah, Internet explorer or Edge. I'll give an alternative

Comment: Please note that my solution using addEventListener is recommended. Unobtrusive event handling and DRY (don't repeat yourself)

Comment: Please see updated code which is faster since it only loops over the checked boxes

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Simple JS. All I did was put each price in the value of the checkboxes and get the values in javascript. Sorry if the pricing didn't match I just putted random numbers. Hope this helps.

```js
function checkPrice() {
  var total_price = 0;
  var chosen_item = document.querySelectorAll("input:checked");
  for (var i = 0; i < chosen_item.length; i++) {
    total_price = parseInt(total_price) + parseInt(chosen_item[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "Total Price:" + total_price;
}
```

```html
<label for="bedroomcleaning">Bedroom: </label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-4" onclick="checkPrice()" value="4">Dust all ceiling fans/light/fixtures within reach.<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-5" onclick="checkPrice()" value="5"> Change sheets and/or fold clothes if requested by client.<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-6" onclick="checkPrice()" value="6"> Straighten up, put toys away, make beds, fold clothes and put on bed. Straighten papers and put in a pile. DO NOT THROW AWAY ANY PERSONAL ITEMS!<br><br>
<label for="bathroomcleaning">Bathroom: </label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-1" onclick="checkPrice()" value="1"> Clean bowl and wipe down toilet cover, seat, under seat, base and behind the base.<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-2" onclick="checkPrice()" value="2"> Clean all mirrors.<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="box-3" onclick="checkPrice()" value="3"> Clean countertops and backsplashes.<br>
<label for="bathroomprice" id="price">Total Price: </label>
```

Comment: It is not recommended to have inline event handlers

Comment: Thank you! This helps too! I'm just trying to write this as simply as possible.

Comment: @Angel the code is simple. You can even make it simpler. I'm just busy right now haha

Comment: This for example: `var total_price = parseInt(total_price) + parseInt(chosen_item[i].value);` can be written `total_price += +chosen_item[i].value;` - you should not repeat the var either

Comment: However `document.querySelectorAll("input:checked")` is better than my original

Comment: @mjplungjan, As what I have said, I'm busy, I just wrote it for like a minute. I'm on the road. I will edit it later on. Don’t try to step down to compete with a beginner like me ;)